# DVWA database connection is not working

Tags: php, mysql, database, penetration-testing

I'm having trouble connecting to a dataase with the following error:

> Could not connect to the database.
>   Please check the config file.

I have tried changing the `$_DVWA[ 'db_server' ]` to `'localhost'` but that didn't work and I tried chainging `$_DVWA[ 'db_port ']` to `3306`, but that didn't work either. The password is empty.

The config file looks like this:

```
<?php

# If you are having problems connecting to the MySQL database and all of the variables below are correct
# try changing the 'db_server' variable from localhost to 127.0.0.1. Fixes a problem due to sockets.
#   Thanks to @digininja for the fix.

# Database management system to use
$DBMS = 'MySQL';
#$DBMS = 'PGSQL'; // Currently disabled

# Database variables
#   WARNING: The database specified under db_database WILL BE ENTIRELY DELETED during setup.
#   Please use a database dedicated to DVWA.
$_DVWA = array();
$_DVWA[ 'db_server' ]   = '127.0.0.1';
$_DVWA[ 'db_database' ] = 'dvwa';
$_DVWA[ 'db_user' ]     = 'root';
$_DVWA[ 'db_password' ] = '';

# Only used with PostgreSQL/PGSQL database selection.
$_DVWA[ 'db_port '] = '5432';
#this can be 3306 or 5432

# ReCAPTCHA settings
#   Used for the 'Insecure CAPTCHA' module
#   You'll need to generate your own keys at:         https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create
$_DVWA[ 'recaptcha_public_key' ]  = '(did not want to disclose this)';
$_DVWA[ 'recaptcha_private_key' ] = '(did not want to disclose this)';

# Default security level
#   Default value for the secuirty level with each session.
#   The default is 'impossible'. You may wish to set this to either 'low', 'medium', 'high' or impossible'.
$_DVWA[ 'default_security_level' ] = 'impossible';

# Default PHPIDS status
#   PHPIDS status with each session.
#   The default is 'disabled'. You can set this to be either 'enabled' or 'disabled'.
$_DVWA[ 'default_phpids_level' ] = 'disabled';

# Verbose PHPIDS messages
#   Enabling this will show why the WAF blocked the request on the blocked request.
#   The default is 'disabled'. You can set this to be either 'true' or     'false'.
$_DVWA[ 'default_phpids_verbose' ] = 'false';

?>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Yuo should first try attaching to the database outside of PHP. Perhaps via the commandline mysql commands.

Comment: make sure you have started the mysql and apache2 services

Comment: You are using Postgres PORT, but trying to connect to Mysql ? change port `$_DVWA[ 'db_port ']` to `3306`

Answer (score 0):

`$_DVWA['db_server']   = '127.0.0.1:3306'; (Or the port that you use)`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27106139)

Comment: Actually @Mirco that is a plausible solution that works for non-PGSQL backends, but it is low quality and should offer a more detailed explanation.